# A Foreign key refering EntityA from EntityB has the wrong number of column. should be 1

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I know this question already asked before, but it isn't working with me. :/
I have two Entities: "Product" and "Finish" with unidirectional many-to-many relationship, where Product is dominant.

I'm trying to do this way:

First, in my Product class, I have:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="produto_has_finalizacao",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="produto_iditem"),
            @JoinColumn(name="produto_classificacao_idclassificacao"),
            @JoinColumn(name="produto_material_idmaterial"),
            @JoinColumn(name="produto_tamanho_idtamanho"),
            @JoinColumn(name="produto_cor_idcor")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="finalizacao_idfinalizacao")})
public List<Finalizacao> getFinalizacoes(){
   return this.finalizacoes; 
}

public void setFinalizacoes(List<Finalizacao> newValue){
    this.finalizacoes = newValue;
}
```

Now, in my Finish class, I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="finalizacao")
public class Finalizacao implements MtiModel{

private final SimpleIntegerProperty idFinalizacao;
private final SimpleStringProperty descricao;

public Finalizacao(){
    this.idFinalizacao = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    this.descricao = new SimpleStringProperty("");
}

public Finalizacao(int idFinalizacao, String descricao){
    this.idFinalizacao = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idFinalizacao);
    this.descricao = new SimpleStringProperty(descricao);
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="idfinalizacao")
public int getIdFinalizacao(){
    return this.idFinalizacao.get();
}

public void setIdFinalizacao(int newValue){
    this.idFinalizacao.set(newValue);
}

@Column(name="descricao")
public String getDescricao(){
    return this.descricao.get();
}

public void setDescricao(String newValue){
    this.descricao.set(newValue);
}
```

}

Please, someone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards,

Mathias

Comment: What is SimpleIntegerProperty ? Do you save that in the db? add the code for SimpleIntegerProperty . Try to be explicit in your questions. Don't leave any thing to be guessed by the community.

Comment: Hey man, tks for answer. SimpleIntegerProperty is a wrapper integer property in JavaFX.